Laptop reboots after a few minutes while plugged in and under low load
For the past couple weeks I've been experiencing random reboots that are very reminiscent of PC power failures. No BSOD, no crash message, no information, no logs, no minidump files, nothing in event viewer. Just a black screen followed by a reboot.
I've tried every solution I've seen online, such as an SFC scan, reinstalling drivers, RAM tests, several drive health diagnoses, cleaned the internal hardware, and even have fully reinstalled Windows. At this point, I think I've narrowed down the circumstances in which the reboot occurs, but I just don't know how to continue solving it since it doesn't appear anyone online has had quite the same issue I do.
The circumstances in which the reboot occurs are as follows:

My laptop must be plugged in. If my laptop is on battery it works completely fine and never reboots.
I must not be playing a game, as I can go for multi-hour sessions on intensive software with no issues.

The amount of time after starting my computer before the reboot occurs can vary from under 10 minutes to several hours, so although I'll add that my computer did not reboot after six hours in Safe Mode, I can't include that as a guaranteed way to avoid the issue entirely.
To be clear, as far as I can tell everything else is working fine. The computer runs great, especially with the new install of Windows cleaning up any bloat. The battery still charges completely fine, so for the time being I can get away with launching a game to play whenever I need charge and then unplugging it whenever I need to do work. Whenever the laptop does reboot, the temperatures are completely fine based on internal readings and also the physical temperature of the device, especially compared to how hot my laptop is seemingly allowed to get while gaming.
Just looking for any possible ideas on how to further troubleshoot from this point, or if anyone has experienced a similar issue and might have a solution to offer. The laptop is four years old, so I'm not ruling out hardware malfunctions yet. Also worth noting that I'm stuck with Aptio Setup Utility as my UEFI, which has, for all intents and purposes, zero usable information or settings, so ideally a solution needs to be found sans BIOS.
Device Specs:

OS: Windows 10 22H2
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz 2.21 GHz
Memory: 16.0 GB
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 with Max-Q Design
Manufacturer: Gigabyte
Model: AERO 15-X9



Try plugging PS into another AC outlet, in a different location in the house, to check if an outlet is miswired (hot-neutral), introducing hum. 2. Since it works fine on battery, the power supply might be failing at low load. If you can, borrow a similar supply to test. A new supply can be found on Amazon for US$35 and more (and far more). Also -- try turning up brightness, adding devices such as a USB-powered fan, light or coffee warmer, or other way to use more power, to see if issue occurs only when power drain is low.

